# NSURLRequest has serious problems in iOS

Tags: ios, url, caching

I am unable to delete the cache for a request, on top of that I can't use **NSURLRequestCachePolicy** to Ignore local and remote cache data. What to do?

It seems impossible to just ignore the cache.

**Some things that I have tried but they didn't work:**

- Removing the cache for a specific request
- Removing all cache
- Creating a request with a ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData policy

Do you have any suggestions?

The thing that we can't get rid of the cache reminds me of the quote: *"Once you go black you never go back"*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question: Resetting the NSURLSession seems to work, I did that along with having a request with a ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData policy, I don't know if it will work without that, but in this combination they seem to work.

I have reseted the URLSession with this code: with a ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData policy